# Keras LSTM: predict multiple sequences from single input array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have input of shape `(748, 1, 7)`, i.e. 748 training examples consisting of a single 7-feature array (ratio of 5 items + 2 extra numbers). What I would like to do is train a network that would output 20 arrays of 5 values. Think of it as how many of each of the 5 types of items should be in each of the 20 bins, with their total ratio set by the input, hence `Y` has the shape `(748, 20, 5)`.

**My code so far** (no optimization attempted, just trying to get the output to work):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(20, input_shape=(1, 7), return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(5)))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

**The problem:** when I run `model.predict()` on test data, I get an output of the shape `(250, 1, 5)` instead of `(250, 20, 5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know does it make sense to your data or not, however if you reshape output of first layer for each sample from `(1,20)` to `(20,1)`, then you will get what you want:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(20, input_shape=(1, 7), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Reshape((20,1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(5)))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 1, 20)             2240      
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_2 (Reshape)          (None, 20, 1)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_2 (TimeDist (None, 20, 5)             10        
=================================================================
Total params: 2,250
Trainable params: 2,250
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---

**UPDATE**: As you have said in comments, it is also possible to resolve the issue with `RepeatVector(n)` layer, but it is not as easy as `Reshape` since it expects input as `(num_samples, features)` and it adds another dimension to your data and makes it `(num_samples, n, features)`.

Since your input shape is `(784, 1, 7)` it can not resolve your issue, unless you first squeeze your data to `(784,7)` using `numpy.squeeze` and apply `RepeatVector(20)` to make it `(784,20,7)`. Then everything will be ok.

Furthermore since `Dense` layers will be apply on last dimension, using `Reshape` should have less trainable parameters than `RepeatVector`.

Here I have added the code to use `RepeatVector`:

```
train_set = np.squeeze(train_set) #reshape from (784,1,7) to (784,7)

model = Sequential()
model.add(RepeatVector(20, input_dim=7))
model.add(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(5)))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential_15"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
repeat_vector_8 (RepeatVecto (None, 20, 7)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_10 (LSTM)               (None, 20, 20)            2240      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_4 (TimeDist (None, 20, 5)             105       
=================================================================
Total params: 2,345
Trainable params: 2,345
Non-trainable params: 0
```

As you can see trainable parameters are more. However you should test both of them on your data and check which one suits more to your data.

Comment: Thank you, that has solved the issue, plus I learned the `Reshape` layer could be a powerful tool ! Another thing I found to work was using `RepeatVector` just before the LSTM layer, although I am still quite unsure on what the difference in impact is of the two ways on the output.

Comment: You can not use simply use `RepeatVector` since it expects input as `(num_samples, features)` and it adds another dimension to your data and makes it `(num_samples, n, features)`, but your input shape is `(784, 1, 7)`. Unless you squeeze your data to `(784,7)` using `numpy.squeez` and apply `RepeatVector` to make it `(784,20,7)`. Then everything will be OK. Furthermore since `Dense` layers applies on last dimension, using `Reshape` have less trainable parameters than `RepeatVector`. I will update my answer to add more info.